# Eclipse IDE is taking very long to open an error location

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ide, eclipse-rcp

When an error happens while running a RCP-Project, **Eclipse shows the location of the error** in the Console view. You can click on the filename and Eclipse will immediately opened the file and put the cursor in the correct line.

Since a few days it **takes my Eclipse installation very long** to do that (several minutes).
In the Progress view I see a "Searching" process running and after a long time the file will be opened.

Do you have any ideas what could be the cause of that long duration?

Or  how I could find out what Eclipse is doing while taking so long?

===
Update:
Setting up a completely new workspace solved the problem. In the new workspace opening the error location works fine.

**I'd still like to know** what I could do in such a case to **find out what Eclipse is working on** (and taking so long for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine that a good jumping off point might be the class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.FollowHyperlinkAction`.

If you set a breakpoint in `FollowHyperlinkAction.run()`, you could walk down into `IHyperlink.linkActivated()` and see just what's going on.